# The Venn diagrams on our about page should have a different colour

Tags: feature-request, design

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/about

It's clearly an aesthetic call, but I think that having the Venn diagrams in four shades of yellow is not pleasing or readable at all.

Can we use different colours?